# I’m not subject to conviction

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> My prefix is a preposition
>   My infix is an exclamation
>   My suffix may be a fraction
>   I’m not subject to conviction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think this is

> innocent

My prefix is a preposition

> in

My infix is an exclamation

> no!

My suffix may be a fraction

> cent is 1/100th of a dollar

I’m not subject to conviction

> I'm innocent :)